# Fetch only particular value of a json format using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column which contains the below json formats:

{"events": null, "game": "yes", "catch": "yes", "throw": null}

{"events": null, "game": "yes", "catch": "no", "throw": null}

I wanted to iterate and fetch only the catch value ie "yes","no" from the json and store it in the same dataframe column.

**Desired output:**

## df_merge['PDH_Value']

yes

no

**Tried the code and getting the below code:**

```
df_merge['PDH_Value'] = df_merge['PDH_Value'].split() 
for i in df_merge['PDH_Value']: 
 df_merge['PDH_Value'] = i[2]['catch']
```

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: What is the end goal here? Can you show an example of what `df_merge` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

[`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) transforms a list of unserialized json objects to columns. We can simply use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/json.html#json.loads) to parse the strings:

```
>>> pd.json_normalize(df['PDH_Value'].apply(json.loads))
  events game catch throw
0   None  yes   yes  None
>>> pd.json_normalize(df['PDH_Value'].apply(json.loads))['catch']
0    yes
Name: catch, dtype: object
```

If you have empty or missing values, you can use the following lambda inside the apply instead of just `json.loads`:

```
lambda j: json.loads(j) if j and pd.notna(j) else {}
```

Comment: How to assign back to the same column ie df_merge[PDH_Value] ?

Comment: Getting error as  raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: You have empty values in your json column.  Try something like `lambda j: {} if pd.isna(j) or not j else json.loads(j)` to parse json

Comment: Did that work for you @Karthikchengalvarayan?